# Stretchable dynamic custom UITableViewCells

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCells` (rounded corners, custom background and so on). My data is also dynamic, the problem here is that when the label gets too long the image (mainly the highlights and the rounded corners) get stretched out.

What's a good solution to this? Right now I'm creating a cell in IB WITHOUT AutoLayout and resizing everything to fit programatically with `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

One I can think of:

1) Keep the background's image view the same size and overlay another image on top of it that extends to the bottom. This seems really hackish and seems like a bad idea in general.

2) Custom draw everything in code.

Thoughts?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you need, but have a look at the resizableImageWithCapInsets: method of UIImage.

Answer (score 0):

Probably need more information on how you're setting up everything (using IB or programmatically creating stuff? using autolayout? using resizing masks?)

If your label gets really long, you could stick your label inside a UIScrollView and set a fixed size for the scroll view.

Comment: Edited, I'm using resizing masks but changing the necessary stuff programatically as the label grows.